# Keras training accuracy only changing a bit, and after a few epochs it is always the same

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I try to train a model, which can detect if a person fell. I have a dataset which contains accelerometer and gyroscope x,y,z data. It has multiple type of human activity, and as well multiple type of falls. I reduced it as fall or not fall data, so I don't care about what kind of activity type is it actually. When I try to rain the model, the val_accuracy and the accuracy is not really changing. And what is weird, that at the first epoch the accuracy is already really hihgh. What can I do, or am I miss something? Maybe my dataset isn't good for training?

Here is my model:

```
model4 = Sequential()
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model4.add(LSTM(units=100, input_shape=(1000, 6), kernel_initializer='normal'))
model4.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model4.compile(loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model4.fit(train_set, train_labels_int, epochs=100, batch_size=100, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[early_stopping])
_, accuracy = model4.evaluate(train_set, train_labels_int, batch_size=200)

print(accuracy)
```

And here is the epochs:

```
Epoch 1/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 52ms/step - loss: 0.6623 - accuracy: 0.6632 - val_loss: 0.6074 - val_accuracy: 0.7833
Epoch 2/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4808 - accuracy: 0.8209 - val_loss: 0.4284 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 3/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4429 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.4268 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 4/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4412 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.4270 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 5/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 48ms/step - loss: 0.4409 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.4259 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 6/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4403 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.4253 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 7/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4402 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.4258 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 8/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 48ms/step - loss: 0.4399 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.4256 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 9/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4397 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.4267 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 10/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 47ms/step - loss: 0.4394 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.4276 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 11/100
81/81 [==============================] - 4s 48ms/step - loss: 0.4392 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.4265 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
45/45 [==============================] - 1s 20ms/step - loss: 0.4370 - accuracy: 0.8401
0.8401111364364624
```

I tried multiple models, but it is always ends up with val_accuracy = 0.8489.
The dataset has a shape (9000,1000,6) as I have 9000 events, the time step is 1000 which is 5 seconds of recording, and each time step has the 3 acceleration and 3 gyroscope values.
I am normalizing the data with StandardScaler, but without normalizing is the same result.

Comment: If you are doing binary classification with two output neurons, you  should use a softmax activation at the output, not sigmoid

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon you run into is called `underfitting`. This happens when the amount our quality of your training data is insufficient, or your network architecture is too small and/or not capable to learn the problem.

Try normalizing your input data and experiment with different network architectures, learning rates and activation functions.

Comment: Well I think the original dataset is good, but I dont't really know how to use it. It has 1789 falls and ~2700 daily activity measurements, but not all is the same length. Some data is 100 sec long, and some is only 12 sec long, so do you have any good advice how can I train a model with this kind of dataset? I mean is it possible, to add different shape of data to the model, to learn from it? I am really new in this, so I don't really know how to prepare my data. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur for multiple reasons:

1. You have imbalanced dataset and forget to weight your classes before training. Use https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi2j_umq4z4AhUV7rsIHT3tBpIQFnoECAgQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscikit-learn.org%2Fstable%2Fmodules%2Fgenerated%2Fsklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html&usg=AOvVaw0mXpmS8-BVTAbAN0I0WxEc to fix it.
2. As previous answer said, it can be underfitting so your model is not learning anything. In order to fix that just try to increase the number of parameters in your model, to increase the amount of data into the learning process, and increase the learning rate from your optimizer.

(Hope it will help and I'm open to any corrections regarding what I just said)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31916859)